# Loading page from wikipedia search query errors when page exists

Tags: python, wikipedia

Running this code errors when the page definitely exists as I use the python wikipedia library to get the page in the first place.

```
import wikipedia

wikiResults = wikipedia.search("megaman 64")
result = wikiResults[0]
page = wikipedia.page(result)
```

The error returned:

```
wikipedia.exceptions.PageError: Page id "mega man legends video games" does 
not match any pages. Try another id!
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Edit: Provided MCVE

Comment: Please provide [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it looks like either a misuse of the library or a bug.

Comment: @yeputons MCVE provided.

Comment: Just made a PR to fix this https://github.com/goldsmith/Wikipedia/pull/177

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I fixed this error by looking at the github solved issues.

When running the below line auto suggest is set automatically to true

```
page = wikipedia.page(result)
```

Disabling this fixes the issue:

```
page = wikipedia.page(result, auto_suggest=False)
```